# Tkinter get partial input from Entry box

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter in Python and I am using it to build a UI for work purposes.

The UI will allow you to search through a list of businesses in a database by either a retailer ID (Integer), retailer name or username.

I have tried searching online and spent ages trying to find what I am looking for on Stackoverflow but can't find what I need.

What I am really struggling with is being able to search by partial strings in the search box and the results to display in a list box. The code below allows me to return a list of businesses but only if I type the EXACT name of the business as it appears in the database.

What I am trying to achieve is, say that there are 2 retailers in the database (these are just examples obviously):

"Market"
"Supermarket"

If I type "Market" in the entry box, I expect to see both of these in the list box. If I type "Super" or "Supermarket", I expect to see only the "Supermarket" retailer name I also don't want this to be case sensitive.

I will then want to be able to select a business from the results and perform some other tasks like sending out automatic emails.

I have access to a MySQL server database.

Here is the code:

```
# Search businesses
def search_now():
    selected = drop.get()
    sql = ""
    if selected == "Search by...":
        searched_label.config(text="You forgot to pick an option!")
    if selected == "Business Name":
        sql = "SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer_Name like ?"
        searched_label.config(text="Business(s):")
    if selected == "Business ID":
        sql = "SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer like ?"
        searched_label.config(text="Business(s):")
    if selected == "Username":
        sql = "SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Account_ID like ?"
        searched_label.config(text="Business(s):")

    searched = search_box.get()
    #sql = "SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer_Name like ?"
    name = (f'%{searched}%', )
    businesses = c.execute(sql, name)
    businesses = c.fetchall()

    #Clear the listbox
    my_list.delete(0, END)

    if not businesses:
        searched_label.config(text="Business not found")

    else:
        for business in businesses:
            my_list.insert(0, str(business[0]) + " " + business[1] + " " + business[2])


# Entry box to search businesses
search_box = Entry(root)
search_box.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
# Entry box label search businesses
search_box_label = Label(root, text="Enter Business name:")
search_box_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=10)
# Entry box search button for businesses
search_button = Button(root, text="Search", command=search_now)
search_button.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
# Drop down box
drop = ttk.Combobox(root, value=["Search by...", "Business Name", "Business ID", "Username"])
drop.current(0)
drop.grid(row=1, column=2)

# Create searched result label
searched_label = Label(root, text="")
searched_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, columnspan=2)


# Create a table
title_label = Label(root, text="CRM", font=("Helvetica", 16))
title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, pady=10)


# Create a listbox
my_list = Listbox(root, width=50)
my_list.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=10)


root.mainloop()
```

I hope all this information helps!

Comment: It sounds like your question has nothing to do with tkinter, but rather how to do a wildcard search with sql. You might want to consider rewriting the example to omit the tkinter part.

Comment: Searching for *partial* string in database, you should use `LIKE` instead of `=` in WHERE clause.  Look into MySQL document on how to use LIKE in WHERE clause.

Comment: @BryanOakley I considered leaving out the tkinter code but wasn't sure if it's some of that code that is conflicting with it not running as it should? I have also updated my code above to 'like ?' but the still only returns when you search by an exact match

Comment: @acw1668 good point. I have updated the code to using 'like?' but when I run the above code, I can only get results that have an exact match

Comment: If you look into the MySQL doc, you will know that you need to use `%` to surround your search string, i.e. `name = (f'%{searched}%',)`.

Comment: @acw1668 you sir are a star! That seems to have worked. I was checking the docs but was struggling to find it - so much information there! Can you send me the direct link so that I can read up more about this! I will also update the code above for others!

Comment: See [official doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for this. Apologies for the stupid question, I have read the section but I don't understand why you have used the letter 'f' when wrapping the wildcard around the search string?

Comment: It is Python *f-string* (one of the string formatting feature).

Comment: @acw1668 this is really useful to know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed! The issue was with the way I was searching for a string in the entry box. I needed to use the "f-string" string formatting feature.

Previous error code:

searched = search_box.get()

name = (searched, )

Correct code

searched = search_box.get()

name = (f'%{searched}%', )